# How to use PrimeVue with Nuxt 3 and set global properties for components

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs3, primevue, nuxt3

Does anyone know how to use PrimeVue in Nuxt3 and add a global setting of selectOtherMonths property for every Calendar component?
Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide

I tried configuring PrimeVue in Nuxt3 by following the documentation and setting the primevue object in my nuxt.config.js file. Then, I added a Calendar component to my app, but it didn't have the selectOtherMonths property set as true, which is what I was expecting. I thought that setting the selectOtherMonths property in the primevue object would apply it to every Calendar component in my app. However, it doesn't seem to be working. Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?